# Internal HR wants an in-person meeting to discuss interview feedback

Tags: interviewing, reinterviewing

**Context:** There are two entities of my company locating in the same building. I'm working as an intern at one entitiy, and had an interview for a permanent position in the other entity which is at the same building. There are 3 open positions there, I did a pre-interview with the manager, in which he introduced me about those 3 positions and asked me to think about it and to give him some thoughts about 3 of them. I chose the most interesting and challenging one, but was saying that i'm available for the other two as well.

**What happened**: My interviews (technique and HR) were going quite well during the last week (from my point of view). But it's already one week that I didn't get any feedback/answer from them (it's completely normal in France).

**What's going on**: Yesterday, I wrote an email to the HR person asking for the results my interviews. This morning, I have an email back saying that she proposes me an physical meeting this afternoon in order to give me feedbacks/answers.

What does it mean? What I have to do to be better prepared for it?

Comment: it sounds like you don't have any feedback or answers yet, so why are you calling them strange?

Comment: @KateGregory the feedback meeting is happening this afternoon, so obviously there are some kind of "preliminary" answers. I called it strange because normally answers are given by email/ phone call, not through a meeting.

Comment: There can be a million reasons for that. A million positive and million negative.

Maybe because you are in the same building, she wanted to surprise you by throwing a surprise party?   Or maybe not!

Comment: Welcome to the site Metallica. I'd like to remind you **not to accept an answer too quickly.** [You might want to wait 24 to 48 hours before accepting to give other people a chance to give you a better answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/260382). A question with an accepted answer isn't as likely to receive further attention as one without an accepted answer.

Comment: @Lilienthal Sorry, it's what I did at Cross Validated (a statistical forum) because it's obvious there whether an answer is correct or not. I didn't pay attention that it's not the case here!

Comment: @Metallica No problem. Even on those SE sites it's possible that an answer offering a different or more detailed perspective might come along, hence why users are encouraged not to accept too early.

Comment: I've edited the title of your question since it was a bit vague. Hopefully this better matches your situation and question but please edit it again if it doesn't.

Comment: It sounds like you got exactly what you were looking for. You asked for feedback, and they want to meet with you to give you that feedback. Sometimes, a cigar is just a cigar.

Comment: I don't see how we can answer this. Seems very specific to your particular company's culture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internal interviews are typically handled quite differently from external ones.  Additionally, interns are often handled differently than other internal candidates, because of the fact that they are typically younger and benefit more from (or are in more need of) career development advice.

It's quite normal to give internal candidates substantially more feedback on applications, good or bad, than external ones.  External candidates don't get feedback because it is not in the company's best interest - either it's irrelevant, or you sue them for not hiring you.  Internal candidates, though, the company has many good reasons for giving feedback to them, even if negative: helping them improve their performance, being more likely to retain the employee after a failure to get promoted/transferred, finding them a better fit.

The intern angle makes that even more relevant.  Since interns are usually younger, they may not be as aware of how things went.  They may not be aware of how well they fit in positions - and equally, the company may want to make sure they understand which position they are applying to and will fit in/like the best.

Either way, I don't think the meeting is a negative sign, nor do I think it shows you are more or less likely to get the position.  It's probably just the normal thing they do with internal candidates.  It's a positive sign, insomuch as your company clearly cares enough about you to either give you feedback, to find out what's in your best interest, or to offer you the position - unless it's simply the fact that the HR person's schedule is busy and scheduling a meeting is the easiest way to make sure they actually talk to you.

Answer (score 30):

> Yesterday, I wrote an email to the HR person asking for the results my interviews. This morning, I have an email back saying that she proposes me an physical meeting this afternoon in order to give me feedbacks/answers.
>   What does it mean?

That she'll give you feedback on your interview during that meeting.

> What I have to do to be better prepared for it?

Get a good night's sleep? You don't have any more information now than you did before so there's nothing you actually can or should do to prepare.

It's fairly common for the results or feedback of an interview to be communicated to candidates via email or phone. In your case however, you're located in the same building so **it makes perfect sense for the person handling your candidacy to schedule an in-person meeting**. If you're a particularly strong candidate that meeting might turn into a second interview but you have no way of knowing that in advance.

The golden rule when it comes to interpreting communication with a company or hiring manager: **take what they say at face value**. There is no point in trying to derive a deeper meaning behind a simple email or phone call.

Comment: +1 for the last few lines. Especially when you're talking over the phone or via mail instead of in person, you have barely any nonverbal language to rely on, so just take everything at face value unless their voice is stacked with sarcasm.